# Copyfolder on Docker

Tags: docker

I have folder of images
I have copied that folder by using " COPY images ." command in dockerfile
now I have to run a python code which reads all images on docker
but I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_run.py", line 15, in <module>
    li=os.listdir('images\\')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'images\\'
```

please explain how to read those images in python code?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install opencv-python-headless

COPY model.py .
COPY model_08015_07680.h5 .
COPY images .
COPY labels.txt .
COPY test_run.py .



CMD ["python","./test_run.py"]
```

in test_run.py one of line where i am getting error

```
li=os.listdir('images\\')
```

Comment: Please add the Dockerfile and python code

Comment: I have added files

Comment: What's that backslash on 'images\\' for?   Do you know the python:3 image likes Windows-style path syntax?   If you shell into the container, does the file structure look like you expect?

Comment: i didnt get you? actually i am very new to docker

Comment: @lnx Remove `\\` from images and run, it should work.

Comment: i have changed that line with   COPY images /usr/src/app/images

Comment: is this issue solved?

Comment: yes just mension full path of where to copy folder